# Entries of the matrix variate generalized inverse Gaussian

Tags: distributions, bayesian, simulation, matrix

I'm currently dealing with a Gibbs sampler of the [matrix variate generalized inverse Gaussian](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-319-46128-1_41.pdf) distribution. In order to check the correctness of the Gibbs sampler, I'd like to know what are the distributions of the entries, or at least their expectations.

Comment: This question is far beyond my ability to answer, but maybe you can check one of the special cases described in the paper, like that of reducing to the Wishart distribution.

Comment: @shadowtalker In fact, I studied the question in the literature, and even the expectations are not known in the general case.